# Nonclosing close button in Windows Mobile ( developed with Qt)

Tags: qt, windows-mobile

Whenever I set maximized the Windows Mobile applications by code that I developed with Qt , their titlebar disappear and there remains only Windows Mobile's default Title Bar. However, whenever I click on that X button, Application won't get closed; instead it keeps running behind.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2296/winmobileexit.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2296/winmobileexit.jpg)

After a few Google searches, I realized that this is the [default behaviour for X button on Windows Mobile](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=J44&q=windows+mobile+close+button&aq=f&oq=&aqi=), which is also the cause of my problem; when I want to show the minimized/hided program by clicking Activate from Settings->System->Memory->Running Programs,

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7387/winmobileexit2.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7387/winmobileexit2.jpg)

Application isn't repainted and remains invisible and child widgets respond the respective events:

[alt text http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/5276/winmobileexit3.jpg](http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/5276/winmobileexit3.jpg)

I don't think this behaviour is any way related to my code, as this problem occurs even with the following simple code: ( I would be appreciated if you can test this on your device)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel w("aduket");
    w.setWindowState(w.windowState()|Qt::WindowMaximized);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Although, I have tried to get the close event of that button, I couldn't. Yet again, only solution that cconceived to me is to remove that X button and add an Exit item to the bottom right menu. Is this reasonable? What might be the cause of this behaviour? Do you have any idea how to resolve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you use MagicButton? (Should you not know it, it's a task switcher that also makes the top-right "X" a real close button. http://www.trancreative.com/mb.aspx )

Comment: I don't want to use any additional tool/library, as I try to run this application both symbian and windows mobile. thanks for the suggestion, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Smart Minimize" button is handled by a style bit typically set when the Windows is created - specifically WS_NONAVDONEBUTTON.  For a CF application, this is controlled by setting the MinimizeButton property to false.  In C/C++, it is done by adding the bit when calling CreateWindow or setting the bit afterward (directly or, as Shane suggests, via SHDoneButton).

Qt is obviously creating a Window, so it's in that process that you need to change the style bit.  I'm not a Qt developer, so exactly how it's done in that framework I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

When using .NET/CF, there is a MinimizeBox property on each Form, setting it to false changes the button to [Ok] and it will close the app. I'm guessing Qt might have a similar setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the default windows mobile behavior you will need to call the function [SHDoneButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453682.aspx).

It takes three possible arguments:

- `SHDB_HIDE` - which is the default and WM most likely displays the 'X' button and will minimize your app when it's pressed.  Also note on some devices the 'X' button will send a `WM_QUIT` to your application.
- `SHDB_SHOW` - will show a 'ok' button and will send a IDOK `WM_COMMAND` to your window when pressed.
- `SHDB_SHOWCANCEL` - will show a 'x' button and will send a IDCANCEL `WM_COMMAND` to your window when pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your indispensable answers. They all contributed to my solution. When I tried to change X button to OK button, I found out that there is a [Windows CE specific flag to make OK button visible](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt.html#details).

```
 #ifdef Q_OS_WINCE
       setWindowFlags(windowFlags()|Qt::WindowOkButtonHint);
 #endif
```

after setting that Button, I have overrided event(QEvent*) function to catch the event fired from OK in order to close the application.

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *mEvent)
{   

    if (mEvent->type()==QEvent::OkRequest)
    {
         qApp->closeAllWindows();
         return true; 
    }

    return QMainWindow::event(mEvent);

}
```

and now it works like a charm =)