# qt 'x' doesn't close app when fullscreen

Tags: windows, qt, mobile

I've been banging my head against this one for a while, so i'm finally giving up and asking for help.

My problem is that my program has a settings.ini that i want to update when the program is close.  I have achieved this using:

**kegTrackerce.h**

```
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
```

and

```
 void KegTrackerCE::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        saveSettings();
        event->accept();
    }
```

This saves the settings and closes the program when i go through file and exit which is great but when i click on the "X" in the top right corner, the window disappears but the program doesn't exit (no exit code) plus when i open the application exe again the program opens instantly instead of loading.

I've identified that this only happens when i include the following code

```
KegTrackerCE::KegTrackerCE(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
//A heap of other stuff here
KegTrackerCE::showFullScreen();
}
```

when i comment out showfullscreen, ta dah, the "x" works as it should, the settings file is updated appropriately, the program is cleared from memory and i get a 0 exit code.

I really don't want to leave the app as maximized instead of fullscreen because screen space is limited enough as it is, there's no point having a redundant bar at the top.

Thanks for your help guys, i have tried heaps of stuff, i've included:

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);
```

along with

```
void KegTrackerCE::lastWindowClosed (){
QApplication::quit();
}
```

but that doesn't do anything.

i'm fairly sure the `closeEvent()` isn't getting called at all when the x is pressed when the thing is in fullscreen.

Anyways, Please help!!  Your help will be very much appreciated!!

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of looking around I found this:

[Nonclosing close button in Windows Mobile ( developed with Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079825/nonclosing-close-button-in-windows-mobile-developed-with-qt)

It's a solution but I'm happy with my fix. Basically,  win ce keeps the application running by default when the button is pressed.  There was talk of setting a bit in the style but I think that simply removing the x is the easiest and most effective approach

Answer (score 0):

"i'm fairly sure the closeEvent() isn't getting called at all when the x is pressed when the thing is in fullscreen" put a break point inside the function and check, because i don't see any reason for closeEvent is not called.

And call `hide()` inside the closeEvent before `event->accept();`. May not be a solution but just to check

Comment: Add QMainWindow::closeEvent(event) inside KegTrackerCE::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)

Comment: hay thanks for your response.  I've tried both the hide and the the qmainwindow approach.  i don't know why the close event isn't being called when the x pressed, how do i put a break point in?

Comment: Depends on the IDE you use, I use visual studio. Can you try instead of showFullScreen(), use showMaximized()

Comment: I have a solution, sort of.  In Main.cpp i put
    w.showFullScreen();//showMaximized();

Comment: it isn't a fix, but it uses up more screen space, and now the x in the corner is gone.  so the only way to exit the program is through file then exit and that correctly executes the closeEvent and saves the settings.ini.

Why this didn't work is going to seriously bug me, but i have something to work with now so i'm happy.  Thanks again for your help Vinod!